# patch panels... or directly to the switch?

Tags: switch, ethernet, networking

does it make a difference in terms of signal quality if I connect the Ethernet cabling:

- from the wall-plugs to the patch-panel and from the patch-panel to the switch with a cord.

as opposed to:

- from the wall-plugs directly plugged to the switch.

Comment: Even if it did, you should still use a patch panel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your question was:

> does it make a difference in terms of signal quality

There will always be some physical layer signaling that is less than perfect, depending on the quality of the link (cabling, distance, patch cords, patch panels, ambient noise, etc.) as well as the characteristics of the ethernet port at the other end of the link.

However, most interfaces are designed to tolerate mild degradation with no loss in link performance.  All other things being equal the addition of a patch panel between two endpoints is negligible on signal quality if the patch panel is properly cabled/terminated.

Answer (score 2):

What if you get a new type of switch that mounts the other way and your cables no longer reach?  What if you move the switch to the other end of the server closet?  That is why people use patch panels.

Answer (score 0):

Ethernet will work reliably provided you comply with its cabling rules. Anyone who does Ethernet cabling professionally should know and understand the cabling rules. It is not difficult to wire up patch panels without violating those rules.

Comment: thank you. is there any reference that you can give me regarding those rules? the best resource to learn more about it?